# How is My website is bigger than i wanted it?

Tags: html, css

My website is bigger than I wanted it. It created a scroll bar on the bottom to scroll left and right but I want it only as big as my screen, something went wrong while doing CSS.

```css
* body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 90px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
}

nav .logo {
  padding: 22px 20px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

nav ul li a {
  line-height: 80px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border-radius: 6px;
  /* pri hoveri spraví z ostrého rámčeka okolo položky menu oblý */
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(background.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0 8%;
}

.container h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  font-weight: 800;
  position: relative;
}

.container h1::after {
  content: '';
  background: #303ef7;
  width: 100px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  /* zoradí jednotlivé services vedla seba*/
  grid-gap: 30px;
}

.service {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  transition: transform 0.5s, background 0.5s;
}

.service i {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #303ef7;
}

.service h2 {
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.service:hover {
  background: #303ef7;
  color: #fff;
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.service:hover i {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>WEBTERAZ Prvy Pokus</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/227b5da2e1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <nav>
    <div class="logo">Webteraz.sk</div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">O nás</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Portfólio</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section></section>

  <div class="container">
    <h1>Our Services</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="service">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-code"></i>
        <!--Ikona </> z font awesome -->
        <h2>Web Design</h2>
        <p> Lorem ipsum WEB DESIGN sit amet, consectetur adipisciring.</p>
      </div>


      <div class="service">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-palette"></i>
        <!--Ikona palety z font awesome -->
        <h2>Logo pre firmu</h2>
        <p> Lorem ipsum LOGO sit amet, consectetur adipisciring.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="service">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-screwdriver-wrench"></i>
        <!--Ikona kluča a šrobovaku z font awesome -->
        <h2>Údržba vašej stránky</h2>
        <p> Lorem ipsum ÚDRŽBA sit amet, consectetur adipisciring.</p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>


<!--Video koniec na 3:34-->

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue here is that the container is 100% + 8% padding each side, so 116% of total screen width. That creates a scrollbar on the X axis.

To overcome this you've got two solutions:

- add `box-sizing: border-box` to the `.container`. Read more about box-sizing [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
- calculate the total width of the `.container` to be 100% - 16%, because padding takes 16%. You could use `width: calc(100% - 16%)` to do that.

I prefer the `box-sizing` solution myself. It's actually not a bad idea to put that into the `*` selector so it matches every element you create.

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box` should absolutely be your default for all projects. [1](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/), [2](https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)